# CircleCI error ('<<' must be escaped as '\\<<' in config v2.1+)

Tags: circleci

```
- build-deploy-dev:
          context: dev-team
          requires:
            - test_app
                <<:*onlyMain\<<
```

I've used `"\\<<"` as well but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using just one backslash.  The error message may be getting escaped somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A single backslash worked for me, but I got thrown off because `<<` in comments also has to be escaped. So in the end it looked like:

```yaml
command: |
  # we need to escape \<< even in comments
  cat \<<END_HEREDOC
    my heredoc
  END_HEREDOC
```